# Angular create component with ViewContainerRef when the component class name in variable

Tags: angular, dynamic, components

I have a question please.

Is there a component name array:

```
private componentArray: string[] = ['PageOneComponent', 'PageTwoComponent', 'PageThreeComponent', 'PageFourComponent'];
```

How can I pass the component names to create the component with `ViewContainerRef.createComponent`?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It needs to be classes. You could convert your array to:

```
private componentArray: Type<any>[] = [PageOneComponent, PageTwoComponent, PageThreeComponent, PageFourComponent];
```

Or if you need labels :

```
private componentArray: Type<any>[] = [{label: 'foo', component: PageOneComponent}, ... ];
```